# How can I get the count of sub-object in a s3 json file using s3-select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3-select

I am storing my json files in **aws-s3** using Ruby-on-Rails. The object looks like,

```
{
  status: "Success",
  created_at: "19 Jan 2019",
  employees:[
     {"name":"name1", "id":"1"},
     {"name":"name2", "id":"2"},
     {"name":"name3", "id":"3"}
  ]
}
```

I want to get the count of **employees** object using **s3-select**.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found a solution for this.

I just used the following query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM S3Object[*].employees[*]
```